# Why were my flagging of posts as being offensive resolved as disputed?

Tags: discussion, offensive, disputed-flags

I flagged these two questions as being offensive:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239379/mapping-webdav-network-drive-in-explorer-doesnt-work-for-certain-url-only
- [Derive from a generic class bothers designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534395/derive-from-a-generic-class-bothers-designer)

You'll need to look at the edit history to see why. Both questions were edited by a diamond mod to remove the offensive language.

But my two flags were resolved as *disputed*. Could somebody explain why they were resolved and disputed rather than helpful? Should I refrain from flagging such posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The offensive flag is meant to be used for posts which are *only* offensive and **should be flat-out deleted**. If you can just edit out the curse word or two and the question will be fine, that's not something that warrants an offensive flag - it warrants an edit.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. As a side note, if I could have seen that information in the response to my flag, I could have learnt the lesson and avoided asking this question.

Comment: That has to do with the way I ended up clearing them. I probably should have declined them with a message, but I ended up just clearing them off the question manually for whatever reason (that method automatically disputes them).

Comment: It's cool. Thanks for helping. And thanks for your work as a diamond mod. Always appreciated.

Comment: Given that these two questions were from the same user, it seems likely that he will continue using such language. Is there a mechanism for him to be notified that such language is not acceptable?

Comment: If the problem continues, we are able to send a message to him.